# fs.renameSync() creates a 2ed file with a timestamp in the title

Tags: node.js, linux, fs

I am using fs.renameSync() to move a file to an archive folder:

```
fs.renameSync(files_path + filename, files_path + 'archive/' + filename);
```

The problem is, in the archive folder I now find an extra file, 2ed file has a timestamp in the filename:

```
filename.csv
filename 2020-05-15-13-34-53.csv
```

Anyone has an idea where this 2ed file is coming from?

Comment: Show your relevant code that is handling files.

Comment: @Azeem there is no more relevant code. This fs.renameSync is the only code that does anything to the file. I tried to google for this problem but I can't find anything. So my theory is, this is not coming from node.js but from the server provider.

Comment: That might be the case. You need to check the file creation date/time/size, etc. to make sure. I tested your use-case on my side and it works as expected.